# How can you escape a man strangling your neck from behind, on the floor?

Tags: self-defense, chokes

How could've the naïve deputy in *No Country For Old Men* (a 2007 film)  escaped or saved himself? Apprise me if you know of any source, but this attack appears realistic and must've been tried in real life? [Here's a 3 minute video clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_9KNP9I6YA). Kindly see the GIF below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strangle or choke requires pressure on the blood vessels and/or windpipe.

- Move to reduce, not increase pressure. Pulling away and sitting up will increase pressure.
- Get your chin underneath the choke, which will relieve the pressure on the blood vessels and windpipe. Push the opponents hands down towards your feet and move your body up towards their head, then drop your chin.
- Turn in and face the opponent, so you can use your own weapons (whether actual weapons, punches, or other techniques you would use to attack someone in front of you).

If you are the choker, you restrict movement using your legs. I would expect that a trained person would escape this entertainment version of a choke easily.

This position is quite similar to a collar choke (*okuri eri jime*) in judo or BJJ.

Comment: Thanks! "so you can use your own weapons." In this scene, the deputy didn't appear to have any weapons. I don't think he had a sidearm holstered. Then what could've the deputy done? Don't hesitate to edit your answer to answer this, rather than write a new comment.

Comment: "Hold the opponents hands down and move your body up, then drop your chin." Are there any pictures or GIFs showing this? If you hold your opponent's hands down, then won't their hands restrict your body movement even more? Then how can you "move your body up"?

Answer (score -3):

Jam an elbow and break a rib. The opponent has presented their chest to your elbows.

Or poke an eye out. Proper strangling technique is to tuck your head onto the victim's back as to prevent that.

What is illustrated is extremely poor strangling technique! The victim could even elbow the killer's balls!

Comment: Poking eyes and elbows to ribs, he? You realise that this is practically impossible in that position? So yes, obviously, it is not obvious ‍♂️